# Best way to calculate a specific median

Tags: median, age

I have a strange question about calculating median.

**Context :**

I have a listing with people who subscribe to an insurance : 
They subscribe from DATE A
to DATE B
(at date B, they leave because they do not need it anymore, or they die, or they find better, whatever!)

I have the listing from past 20 years, so it's a huge amount of people and data.

What I need now, is to calculate : 
- the median age of people who take this insurance
- the median time they keep this insurance before they leave

**My question is :**

What's the best (most relevant) way to calculate this?

If I take the age for all people (even people that do not have insurance anymore) from the beginning, this is not really relevant.

If I take the age for all people who still have the insurance "active" today, this is not relevant neither.

There is no "fixed" age to subscribe, so I have people in my list who took this insurance at age 40 and now are 65 years old and still active. But, opposite, I have in my list people who subscribed at age 60 and left at 62. All this data is over years and years. So, medians calculated in 1980 were "relevant" since activity was not running for years and years, but right now it's slightly different...

Comment: What exactly is your goal?  Calculating a median is straightforward, but it appears you have some more specific objective in mind.

Comment: The road you take depends not only on your starting point, but your intended destination.  Are you looking for a good fit, or to attribute a particular behavior to a particular cause?  Best is meaningless without a rubric, a measure of 'bestness'.  You have not supplied that.

Comment: Well, thanks for your comments. It's like "what's the middle age of the people having this kind of insurance "today" ", BUT today's not really today, and that's the point! What is the "relevant today" in this kind of problem? Only people active + subscribing 'this year' + who left this year (or not)? Same problem about the time they keep insurance, Which people should be taken in account for a relevant "median time" for same "relevant today"? (Not sure I'm clear... sorry about that, it's also confusing to me...)

Comment: Another example, what's the median for "how long do people -nowadays- keep this insurance before they leave"? This is another consistent question, ten years ago people tended to take this insurance when median aged 45 and use to keep it for a median 10 years, now it has changed, people take this insurance later and thus tend to keep it less time... aaaaarhhhh sooo confusing :@